# What expiry date should I see for in-app purchase in the application sandbox?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Let's say a user purchases one product in my app on 11-01-2012 at 10:30 AM. What will be the expiry date for a one month duration product?

Does this depend on the time at which they purchased the product, or only the date?

I am asking because, for one month subscriptions, I am seeing 5 min expiry dates in my application running within the in-app purchasing sandbox.

Answer (score 58):

You know, I don't think this should be closed. It's actually a pretty good question, and a fact about the sandbox that is not well known (which might be why people have voted it down!).

When testing in the sandbox, **time is sped up for subscriptions**. This is not as well documented as it should be. Apple do this so you can better test your renewable subscription logic. So your one month subscription will, *when bought in the sandbox* expire in five minutes.

It is somewhat annoying that this isn't documented anywhere in the *developer* documentation - only in the iTunes Connect documentation. For convenience I've posted the actual 'real world' to sandbox times below:

- 1 week =  3 minutes
- 1 month = 5 minutes
- 2 months = 10 minutes
- 3 months = 15 minutes
- 6 months = 30 minutes
- 1 year = 1 hour

Comment: This question should not be closed, thank goodness for your answer being here.

Comment: I want to add that in sandbox mode, the auto renew happens 5 times only, then the subscription expires as if the user has unsubscribed. This is the only way to terminate a subscription in sandbox

Comment: I have been trying to figure out this for hours. Thank you!! Do you have any link to Apple documentation which documents this??? How did you learn that? Or event a WWDC video or anything. I mean, this is crazy.